# Form fields validation: which characters to include / exclude?

Tags: forms, validation, passwords

A google search gave me the methods to validate form fields, but I can already construct them. My question is, which are the characters that are safe to include and which are to exclude in a form field? Specifically, username and password.

A brief explanation would be nice too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude all characters you will never have inside you datas.
Do you think it would be any sense to have special characters if your usernames/passwords must only contains alphanumeric characters ?

Look at some [REGEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for [JAVA](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) or for [PHP](http://www.expreg.com/).

There is a [regexp reference table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) which could be usefull too.

If you give us more information about the langage you are using, we could maybe help us more.
Have a good day!

**[UPDATE]**
There is the [security reference](http://doc.cenzic.com/sadoc9x14ba847/CPL0001011.htm) which is very good and the [OWASP website](http://www.owasp.org/) which is a real reference for any web security related topics, look at the [OWASP Cheat Sheets](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cheat_Sheets).

```
#**Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerabilities?**
#for any programming language, the chars you should reject or handle properly are:
>     <   (     )     [     ]     '     "     ;     :     /     |

#for PHP, tools to handle with care:
strip_tags(), utf8_decode(), htmlspecialchars(), strtr()

#do Positive/Negative filtering
#check Encoding

#**SQL Injection ?**
#etc...
```

**[/UPDATE]**

Comment: I'm capable of writing the regex for the validation. What I'm asking is, lots of form fields exclude characters such as single and double quotes, commas and periods. I'd like to have a list of commonly excluded / included characters and the reason for it. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: So maybe these [security reference](http://doc.cenzic.com/sadoc9x14ba847/CPL0001011.htm) will give you a lot informations you'll love. The [OWASP website](http://www.owasp.org/) is very good too.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I was looking for. Not sure why but I just didn't google with the right keywords. I'll mark your reply if you put this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you properly sanitize your input and output, there's nothing you need to be afraid of.

**Note:** I'm assuming you're using PHP as your server side language.

First, use `PDO` (or `MySQLi`) with prepared statements, to eliminate the risk of SQL Injection.

Second, anything that *will be displayed on your site* should be sanitized against XSS attacks (so that users don't register a username of `<script>doSomeEvilStuff()</script>`).

That's it basically, if you're really paranoid, you should be using a whitelist (to only allow certain characters) and not a blacklist (to only disallow certain characters), since someone will always find a way to bypass a blacklist, but no one can bypass a whitelist.

For usernames, I don't see the need for anything more than `/[a-zA-Z0-9_.\s!$%^&*\-+=]/` You may think otherwise. In any case, don't allow `` /[`<>(){}[]]/ ``